# Can I draw to the same CGContextRef from multiple threads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, swift, core-graphics

I'm making an app where I want to draw a lot of shapes - circles, boxes, lines, etc.
Millions of them.

To test the performance of this, I threw together this simple UIView. Note that credit is due - I got inspired by [this project](https://github.com/ddeville/Mandelbrot-set-on-iPhone).

```
import UIKit

let qkeyString = "label" as NSString
var QKEY = qkeyString.UTF8String
let qvalString = "com.hanssjunnesson.Draw" as NSString
var QVAL = qvalString.UTF8String

public class RenderImageView: UIView {

    var bitmapContext: CGContext?

    let drawQueue: dispatch_queue_attr_t = {
        let q = dispatch_queue_create(QVAL, nil)
        dispatch_queue_set_specific(q, QKEY, &QVAL, nil)

        return q
    }()

    public override init() {
        super.init()

        render()
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        render()
    }

    override required public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        render()
    }

    public override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if let bitmapContext = self.bitmapContext {
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            let image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext)
            CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, image)
        }
    }

    private func render() {
        dispatch_async(drawQueue) {
            let startDate = NSDate()

            let bounds = self.bounds
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            self.bitmapContext = context

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
            CGContextFillRect(context, bounds)

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.4, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1.0).CGColor)

            for i in 1...1000000 {
                CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, bounds)
            }

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            self.setNeedsDisplay()

            let benchmark = startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
            println("Rendering took: \(-benchmark*1000) Ms")
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine. On my iOS simulator, it takes little over a minute to draw a million circles on top of each other.

I wanted to speed this up, so I tried drawing to the bitmap context from multiple threads.

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()
for i in 1...100 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group)

        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, bounds)

        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
}

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

This did not work, however. I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when calling `CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, bounds)`.

Drawing to a `CGContext` in a background thread seems fine as long as it's the same thread that created it.

Anyone know of a way of getting this to work?

Comment: What happens if you don't reuse the `context` reference, but instead get the current bitmap context?

Comment: The only way to get the bitmap context is to call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext after creating a new image context. Otherwize, UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext will get another context. Drawing to that won't show up in the resulting image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You aren't actually waiting for the group you created to finish -- `dispatch_group_wait` is going to be called in that code before any of the blocks have been executed, so the enter / leave calls inside them won't have any effect. Use `dispatch_group_async` instead (see below).

2) You can't draw to a `CGContext` from two different threads at the same time -- you can see this if you add a println inside your drawing loop. It will work a few times, with varying results, but eventually you'll be end up with an error.

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()
for i in 1...10 {
    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
        for j in 1...100 {
            println("i:\(i), j:\(j)")
            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, bounds)
        }
    }
}
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

Sample output:

```
iiii::::4123,,,,    jjjj::::1111



ii:1, j:2
:5, j:1
i:6, j:1
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

The only solution to this is to jump back on a single thread for drawing, but that defeats what you were trying to do any way. If you have to do lots of calculations to decide what to draw, that could happen on separate threads, but drawing to `CGContext` itself isn't thread safe.

Comment: I guess the best way of using multiple cores then would be to draw "buckets", that is, separate parts of the complete image, then stitch them together.